# Changing UINavigationBar color issues

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am having issues modifying color on a UINavigation bar. I feel like I have tried everything, but my current code is below (MasterViewController.m, my main view):

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
[super awakeFromNib];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9333 green:0.3647 blue:0.3843 alpha:1.0]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9333 green:0.3647 blue:0.3843 alpha:1.0]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];


}
```

Here is my setup in my storyboard:

[image]

Any apparent reason why this isn't working?

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't work, unless it's being called somehow after the nav bar ends up in the window. What have you tried debugging-wise? If you break on `-awakeFromNib` what else is going on? If you call `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] recursiveDescription]` while in that method, is there a view hierarchy? If there is, there shouldn't be! It should show `(null)` to that in the debugger.

Comment: @JasonCoco I actually just gave up and set in the UINavigationBarController view in my Storyboard. Thanks for you input though.